# For SEO what is better, Alias or /Directory/?

Tags: seo

I had `http://foo.tld/` cancelled because foo was a name too similar to a brand, so the DNS authority cancelled it. So I will register `http://bar.tld/` to talk about '*foo*'.

'*foo*' as **ALIAS**:

`http://foo.bar.tld/`

'*foo*' as **/Directory/**:

`http://bar.tld/foo/`

I personally prefer the Alias way, it one less /Directory/.

So my question is, how should I develop the website, or both ways are the same? Can anyone point out the differences?

Comment: Any content on foo.bar.tld will not help bar.tld. The semantic value of foo.bar.tld is no different than bar.tld/foo/. Of the two, I would use bar.tld/foo/ but do not put the home page in /foo. Just put foo stuff in /foo. That way, if you decide to talk about pooh, you have room for /pooh. ;-) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Google has stated, [through Matt Cutts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSiYHG-L_PAhVB64MKHUsjA90QtwIIMDAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_MswMYk05tk&usg=AFQjCNEgB3Y1Dda1Eu_1JWflonyZZphQ8g&sig2=6ZwjJw2l3eHU_sla6FoIGw), that it doesn't matter to them. They also say what I would say, that foo.bar.tld is a separate site from bar.tld and bar.tld/foo is a sub of bar.tld.

So, if you want to keep foo unique from anything else, I would do foo.bar.tld. If foo is part of bar then do bar.tld/foo